# Two balls are dropped from the same height. Ball A is metallic and B, made up of an insulating material. Which of them touches ground first?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, newtonian-gravity

General motion under gravity states that both of them reach the ground simultaneously. But here, ball B reaches first. I searched for the solution but couldn't find any. Does it have anything to do with Earth's electromagnetic field?? If yes, then please explain. Question source
https://questions.examside.com/past-years/jee/question/pspherical-insulating-ball-and-a-spherical-metallic-ball-o-jee-main-physics-motion-bql7sgt3pxedb8dt
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhUZZ.jpg

Comment: where is your evidence?

Comment: Sorry for not doing it earlier. I have attached the image now.

Comment: What's the source of this quiz question?

Comment: I don't get why this has been closed. OP asked a good question based on a quiz he has already taken and wants to know why the answer is what it is. Not all metals are magnetic, so I don't know why the insulating material would hit the ground first. Maybe the insulating material is less dense and the material itself has holes of air throughout (like Swiss cheese), and so there air flow causes some sort of turbulence-like effect that ends up speeding up the insulating ball.

Comment: Now that I think about it though, how can the insulating ball have the same size and mass as the metallic one? That would imply they have the same density which is obviously not true...

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this because it seems like a fine conceptual question. There are no specific numbers in it. Just being from a test/quiz doesn't disqualify a question here, as far as I know.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson Metallic sodium has a density of ~0.97 g/cm^3, pretty similar to that of high density polyethylene (0.94-0.97 g/cm^3), so it wouldn't be too hard to find conducting and insulating balls of virtually identical mass and volume.

Comment: This is a poorly formulated question. There are a lot of effects that could be more important, such as electrostatic forces. It asks the student to read the examiner's mind.

Comment: Voted to close because the actual question doesn’t appear in the body of the question. It only appears in the link. I would happily vote to re open if the actual question is moved into the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web-site's arguement, that the insulating ball will reach the earth's surface first, appears valid *so long as there is some change in the magnitude or orientation of the magnetic field over the path taken by the balls*.

It is probably simplest to argue from the point of view of conservation of energy rather than attempting a force calculation. The changing flux will generate an emf proportional to $\cfrac{d\Phi}{dT}$ that will induce circulating currents and/or charge separation in the conducting ball. So a fraction of the initial gravitational potential energy of the conducting ball will be converted into inductive or capacitive energy storage (and heat as currents decay) instead of kinetic energy, hence it will fall (slightly) slower.

A more extreme version of this behaviour can be observed if you push a (non-ferromagnetic) conductor into a large magnetic field. A copper rod inserted in this manner can feel like it is being pushed through treacle.

Comment: But note that if we're talking about the Earth's magnetic field, this effect will be _extremely_ small. The earth's magnetic field does not change much over a few meters - it's length scale is set by the radius of the Earth. Frankly I suspect the person who wrote this quiz question mistakenly thought that magnetic breaking happens in a constant magnetic field.

Answer (score 1):

If the metallic ball is a conductor then while the ball is falling the conducting electrons will start to accumulate on either side of the ball (due to earth's magnetic field)

At every instant the electrostatic force due to charge accumulation must cancel out the magnetic force(if it's a pure conductor)
on the conducting electrons as it's a conductor.

As someone had already mentioned it starts acting like a capacitor,and we notice that the charge on either side is changing. So a current must be flowing across the ball. Due to this current there is a force on the conductor that opposes the gravitational force.

Hence it's acceleration is lesser than g.

Comment: This only produces a force if the magnetic field is changing along the falling trajectory. And the primary cause of that effect is eddy currents. Not what you describe which is kind of like a change in the hall effect for a conductor moving through a changing magnetic field. The change in the earth's magnetic field along a few meters drop is extremely small, so this effect would be incredibly small, certainly negligible as compared to hundreds of other effects (the length scale for these variations is the radius of the earth!)

Comment: Why is it necessary that the magnetic field should change for this to happen? I didn't assume that it will change anywhere

Comment: Well in more detail, the Hall effect, which is the "electrons going to one side" thing is extremely small in conductors (mostly happens in semiconductors). Order of magnitude if you're falling at 10m/s a 0.1m wide ball will have 50uV across it because of this. With the acceleration $g$ you get $10^{-17}$A and a force of $10^{-22}$N. There is an effect, called magnetic braking, which happens in a changing magnetic field. Someone else posted that this was the effect the question writer was intending to discuss, but they mistakenly thought it happened in the Earth's constant magnetic field.

Comment: okay makes sense

Answer (score -1):

There is an explanation on the question website that appears as you choose the correct answer:

> The correct answer is option C: the insulating ball will reach the
> earth's surface earlier than the metal ball.
>
> When the two balls are dropped from the same height, they will
> experience the same gravitational force, which will cause them to
> accelerate downwards. However, According to Faraday’s law of
> electromagnetic induction motion of metal is opposed by earth magnetic
> field. Which will slightly reduce its acceleration.
> On the other hand, the insulating ball will not experience any
> electromagnetic induction. Therefore, it will accelerate downwards at
> a slightly faster rate than the metal ball. As a result, the
> insulating ball will reach the earth's surface earlier than the metal
> ball.
>
> So, option C is the correct statement.

However, I cannot find this answer convincing! It is not clear how some induced currents appear on the metal ball that possibly resist the gravitational field or the earth's magnetic field according to Lenz's law or something. On [this website](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-does-metal-moving-though-a-magnetic-field-slow-down.1045347/), it is said that there appear eddy currents in the metal ball so that these currents generate their own magnetic field which somehow slows down the moving metal ball since any induced electric current is in a direction such as to ‘oppose its cause’.

However, I am not convinced yet! At most, we can say that the metal ball is full of free electrons and protons that, by subjecting to an external magnetic field, undergo a Lorentz force. This force pushes the electrons toward one side of the ball and makes the ball behave like a capacitor (emf is induced). Therefore, there is an electric field inside the metal ball which is *not* considered to be a perfect conductor that cancels out any internal electric field. Even if we assume that the current that separates the charges inside the metal ball increases due to the increasing Lorentz force, which, per se, is due to the increasing velocity of the electrons along the gravitation direction, the induced magnetic field circulating this current seems to be perpendicular to that of the earth's. It does not seem that this induced magnetic field plays a key role in this scenario to reduce the acceleration of the metal ball unless I misunderstood something.

Comment: Like another answer, you seem to be referring to the hall effect (which is negligible in metals, and only observable in semiconductors), which is different from magnetic braking/eddy currents (which is the principle reason conductors slow down before hitting a magnet). A changing magnetic field induces a current that produces a magnetic field in the opposite direction. The currents decay over time because of the nonzero resistance of the metal. And the provided answer seems to just be wrong. Magnetic braking only happens in a changing magnetic field.

Comment: @AXensen First, what causes the magnetic field to be changing? Second,  please tell me in which direction the Earth's magnetic field is.

Comment: Which direction the earth's magnetic field points varies depending on where you are. At the north pole, it points up. At the equator, it points northish. In Geneva it points a bit up and a bit north. It will change _slightly_ along a dropped ball's trajectory because the field magnitude increases as you move closer to the center of the earth (it is approximately a dipole, and it varies the way a dipole does). In any case, there is _no_ magnetic breaking unless the magnetic field is changing. A constant magnetic field does not slow down a metal's fall.

Comment: @AXensen The changes in the earth's magnetic field are negligible, however, even if such induced currents play a role in reducing the speed/acceleration of the metal ball, we can consider other effects! Assume that the ball is ferromagnetic. Then it becomes a permanent magnet in the Earth's magnetic field and reaches the surface of the earth sooner.